# Prevent overlap with css transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have menu tabs that slide out on hover (using css3 transition) to reveal sub items. If one of the menu tabs is long then it overlaps another element. I would like the menu tab to 'push' this element out of the way when the transition occurs.

It would be great if this could be done without javascript, but I'm mostly sure that's impossible, so if there must be javascript I would prefer JQuery.

Here's an example.

```
<head>
<style>
#menu div
{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    right: 50%;
    transition: right 0.5s;
}

#menu div:hover
{
    right: 0;
}

#menu div h1
{
    float:right;
}

#sidebar
{
    background-color: #999999;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div><h1>Tab 1</h1></div>
        <div><h1>Tab 2</h1></div>
        <div><h1>Tab 3</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"><h1>Sidebar</h1></div>
</body>
```

I would like the tabs to 'push' over the sidebar once the animation brings them close together.

Here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tueg8c76/
Here is the page I'm working on: http://dunamixdanceproject.com/portal.php

Comment: You should create an example (with the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem) and include it in the question itself mate. Questions where the problematic code resides in some external location (which may become inactive after sometime) are generally not encouraged.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could suggest you a little trick.

Add this jQuery to the head inside $(document).ready function.

**JQuery**

```
$('#menu div').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#sidebar').css({'left': '1100px'});
});
$('#menu div').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#sidebar').css({'left': '845px'});
});
```

**CSS** - Add this to **#sidebar**

```
#sidebar{transition: left 1s;}
```

That's all for working it up

Comment: This is almost what I want. With this code #sidebar moves when you hover over a dev, I don't want it to move until the transition brings the div close to #sidebar, giving the illusion that the menu tab is physically 'pushing' the sidebar over